# Is there cumulative sum function in DM-scripting?

Tags: image-processing, projection, dm-script

I would like to do cumulative sum along x or y direction of the image data.
Is there any function in DM-scripting like "cumsum" in Matlib?
Thanks!

for example an image of 4x4 pixels the pixel values are

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
```

cumulative sum along x direction will result in:

```
1 1+2=3 1+2+3=6 1+2+3+4=10
2 5 9 14
3 7 12 18
4 9 15 22
```

Comment: Not everybody knows Matlib and "cumsum", but I assume what you want to have is the projected sum of the image along X and along Y direction, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear enough. the result of cumsum of an 2D image is still a image of the same size of the input image. the value of each  pixels is the sum of all pixels one the left/top along the column/row direction.

Comment: See modified answer below. Does this do what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is it! Thanks! The intrinsic variable method works better!

Comment: Being curious: What is the application of this? (Most people I know of use this type of cumulative summing just to "project" data.)

Comment: I defined a 2D function and want to approximate its integral. Another application, which is not so good with noisy data, is to retrieve phase from its gradient measurement, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differnt ways to achieve this, but potentially the fastest and easiest is to create a "fully binned" version of the image.

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
number sizeX, sizeY
img.GetSize( sizeX, sizeY )

image vSum = Rebin( img, 1, sizeY )
image hSum = Rebin( img, sizeX, 1 )
vSum.SetName( "vertical sum" )
vSum.ShowImage()
hSum.SetName( "horizontal sum" )
hSum.ShowImage()
```

If you want a 2D image as a result, where each pixel holds the sum of all its pixels to the left, you can do this by adding up offset images:

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
number sizeX, sizeY
img.GetSize( sizeX, sizeY )

image vCumSum := img.ImageClone() 
for( number x = 1; x<sizeX ; x++ )
{
    hCumSum += offset( img, -x, 0 )
}
hCumSum.SetName( "horizontal sum (cumulative)" )
hCumSum.ShowImage()
```

Alternatively, you can create an expression using intrinsic variables as in

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
image hCumSum := 0 * img.ImageClone() 
hCumSum += img[icol,irow] + hCumSum[ icol - 1, irow ]
hCumSum.SetName( "horizontal sum (cumulative)" )
hCumSum.ShowImage()
```

---

GMS 3.4 also offers a dedicated, speed optimized command:

```c
RealImage Project( BasicImage img, Number axis )
RealImage Project( BasicImage img, Number axis, Boolean rescale )
void Project( BasicImage img, BasicImage dst, Number axis )
void Project( BasicImage img, BasicImage dst, Number axis, Boolean rescale )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do projection is by matrix multiplication. multiply a 2-D image by a 1-D matrix of 1's will project the image onto 1-D accumulation.

```
number d0, d1
image HProject, VProject, ones, img
img:=getfrontImage()
img.getSize(d0,d1)
ones:=exprSize(1,d0,1) 
HProject=MatrixMultiply(img,ones)
HProject.rotateLeft()
HProject.showImage()
ones:=exprSize(d1,1,1)
VProject=MatrixMultiply(ones,img)
VProject.showImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have one

```
image cumsum(image img)
//  computes the cumulative sum along x direction
{
    number sx, sy
    img.GetSize(sx,sy)

    for(number i=1; i<sx; i++)
    {
        img[0,i,sy,i+1]=img[0,i-1,sy,i]+img[0,i,sy,i+1]
    }
    return img
}

image im=getfrontimage()
im=im.cumsum()
im.showimage()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.